# MBProgressHUD is not animating in determinate mode

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud

MBProgressHUD is not animating when set the `mode` to `.determinate` it just showing the circle instead of animating.

```
self.progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
self.progressHUD?.mode = .determinate
self.progressHUD?.contentColor = .purple
```

[image]

Comment: animating means you want to show the progress

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik true

Answer (score 0):

you need to set progress its value lies between 0 & 1 so you can use it like

```
self.progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
self.progressHUD?.mode = .determinate
self.progressHUD?.contentColor = .purple
self.progressHUD?.setProgress(0.3)
```